# Swift 3 tableViewCell Button, strange behaviour, submit one button and others of the same Cell change as well?

Tags: swift3, xcode8

Repeated on two projects and searched in vain so I hope someone can help...

Created a basic TableViewController and one TableViewCell. Run and press the first button, scroll down and other random buttons also show the same change?

TableViewController

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }

  // MARK: - Table view data source

  override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
  }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 99
  }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ButtonCell", for: indexPath) as! ButtonCell

    cell.rowLabel.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
    cell.tapAction = { (cell) in
      self.showAlertForRow(tableView.indexPath(for: cell)!.row)

    }

    return cell
  }

  // MARK: - Extracted method

  func showAlertForRow(_ row: Int) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(
      title: "BEHOLD",
      message: "Cell at row \(row) was tapped!",
      preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Gotcha!", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (test) -> Void in
      self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }))

    self.present(
      alert,
      animated: true,
      completion: nil)
  }
}
```

Table View Cell

```
//  ButtonCell.swift


import UIKit

class ButtonCell: UITableViewCell {
  var tapAction: ((UITableViewCell) -> Void)?

  @IBOutlet weak var rowLabel: UILabel!

  @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
  @IBAction func buttonTap(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    button.setTitle("Correct", for: .normal)
    tapAction?(self)



  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets begin with the basics. You don't need this:

```
cell.tapAction = { (cell) in
      self.showAlertForRow(tableView.indexPath(for: cell)!.row)
    }
```

You better use the apple framework:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        showAlertForRow(indexPath.row)
    }
```

Second create a method in you cell like

```
import UIKit

class ButtonCell: UITableViewCell {
    var tapAction: ((UITableViewCell) -> Void)?
    @IBOutlet weak var rowLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    @IBAction func buttonTap(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        button.setTitle("Correct", for: .normal)
        tapAction?(self)
    }

    func createCell() {
        button.setTitle("Your button title", for: normal)
    }
}
```

and call the createCell method in your

```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    ...
    cell.createCell()
    ...

}
```

Hope I could help but try to start with the basics here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate

Comment: I don't think he needs the `createCell()` method since he can use the `prepareForReuse()` method provided by Apple.

Comment: its an approach but if he wants to change the data he can create a `createCell(withItem: Item)` and add the item directly to the cell. You can do whatever you want then and your `cellForRowAt` method isn't full with code

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are dequeuing your `UITableViewCells`. In order to solve the problem you should use the `prepareForReuse()` method in your `ButtonCell`. You can save the states of all your buttons and when a cell is being dequeued you can just set the title of the button in this cell in the `prepareForReuse()` method.